# Spring Data JPA Unable to save related entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am learning Spring boot by creating a blog application, which consists of Post and Category models as follows:

**Post**

```java
package com.psquared.blog.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Category category;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String content;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

**Category**

```java
package com.psquared.blog.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    public List<Post> posts;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

    public void setPosts(List<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }
```

After that, I created a command line runner as follows:

```java
@Bean
@Transactional
public  CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(PostService postService, CategoryService categoryService){
        return (args -> {

            Category java = new Category();
            java.setName("java");

            Post p1 = new Post();
            p1.setTitle("post 1");
            p1.setContent("content");
            p1.setCategory(java);

            Post p2 = new Post();
            p2.setTitle("post 2");
            p2.setContent("content 2");
            p2.setCategory(java);

            postService.save(p1);
            postService.save(p2);

        });
    }
```

I am try to save two posts and the related category to db, but for some reason only one post and related category is persisting, the second post is not persisting at all.

Also I am using `cascade.All` option on `Post` table, so I don't need to save the `Category` model manually.

Here is the error I am getting:

```bash
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-01-24T07:48:06.767+05:30 ERROR 30611 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.psquared.blog.model.Category
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:310) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550) ~[spring-orm-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `CascadeType.ALL` on the `ManyToOne` relationship in Post when you save `p1`, the `Category` instance (java) also gets persisted.

```
postService.save(p1);
```

Once the transaction associated with `postService.save(p1)` completes, `Category` (java) becomes a detached entity because it is no longer in the context of an active transaction.

So that it didn't allow you to save it again under a different transaction because the state of the entity is `detached`. This is the reason why you see this exception.

```
detached entity passed to persist: com.psquared.blog.model.Category
```

If you run this operation in the scope of one transaction it should work just fine.
Example:

```
    @Transactional
    public void createAndSavePosts() {
        Category java = new Category();
        java.setName("java");

        Post p1 = new Post();
        p1.setTitle("post 1");
        p1.setContent("content");
        p1.setCategory(java);

        Post p2 = new Post();
        p2.setTitle("post 2");
        p2.setContent("content 2");
        p2.setCategory(java);

        postService.save(p1);
        postService.save(p2);
    }
```

If the problem still persist it’s more likely related to your cascading type, I would try merge and check again.

Comment: the `CommandLineRunner` is already annotated with `@Transactional`. It is still giving the same error.

Comment: Can you try cascade type as MERGE just for testing purposes?

Comment: @Cody if you are planning to use `CascadeType.MERGE` on `Post` entity `Category` attribute, then make sure to save the `Category` entity first like `categoryService.save(java)`

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `Category` entity's `Post` reference as follows

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
public List<Post> posts;
```

Similarly, update the `Post` entity's `Category` reference

```java
@ManyToOne
private Category category;
```

Make corresponding adjustments to the transaction operations

```java
Category java = new Category();
java.setName("java");
categoryService.save(java);

Post p1 = new Post();
p1.setTitle("post 1");
p1.setContent("content");
p1.setCategory(java);

Post p2 = new Post();
p2.setTitle("post 2");
p2.setContent("content 2");
p2.setCategory(java);

postService.save(p1);
postService.save(p2);
```